# How to generate request model having same object which having multiple types

Tags: android, kotlin

How to generate request model having same object which having multiple types:

```
{
      "questionnaire": 2,
      "response": [
        {
          "answer": {
            "id": 8,
            "option_data": {
              "description": "",
              "text": "As much as i ever did",
              "value": "4"
            }
          },
          "question_id": 4
        },
        {
          "answer": {
            "option_data1": [
              {
                "text": "",
                "value": 2
              }
            ]
          },
          "question_id": 2
        }
      ]
}
```

Comment: https://json2csharp.com/json-to-pojo

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin AS Json to DataClass convertor. [You can find here](https://github.com/wuseal/JsonToKotlinClass)

```
data class s(
val questionnaire: Int?, // 2
val response: List<Response>? )

data class Response(
val answer: Answer?,
@Json(name = "question_id")
val questionId: Int? // 4 )



data class OptionData1(
val text: String?,
val value: Int? // 2 )


data class OptionData(
val description: String?,
val text: String?, // As much as i ever did
val value: String? // 4  )


data class Answer(
val id: Int?, // 8
@Json(name = "option_data")
val optionData: OptionData?,
@Json(name = "option_data1")
val optionData1: List<OptionData1>? )
```

As you see there is `?` in some fields. You can use it